# Unable to use Top Panel Menu Places

Tags: mate, shotwell

Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS. When I try to use the top panel Places and select either Home Folder or Desktop I get an error message from Shotwell saying it home is not a file or desktop is not a file.I can get to my files if I select computer which is the third option down.Any suggestions how I can reset the top menu will be highly appreciated. I have deleted the top panel and opened a new panel but it still tries to use shotwell.

Comment: that's strange... have you tried issuing `killall shotwell` in a terminal? Does this behaviour continue after reboot?

Comment: Yes problem persists after reboot. The following was suggested to me: system/preferences/personal/preferred applications then system tab and select caja as file manager. This worked first time ..,.., many thanks to all though.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and use this command to fix the corrupted association

```
xdg-mime default caja-folder-handler.desktop inode/directory
```

This should fix the problem for you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help - much appreciated.  I used the following which worked for me: system/preferences/personal/preferred applications then system tab and select caja as file manager.

Comment: @IEB This answer explains how to do the same thing the command line way :)